# Как скрыть scrollbar в Android Studio и отключить автоматическое всплывание вкладок

Tags: android-studio

Пытался решить сам, но не получилось

1. Я хочу скрыть лифты, показанные на картинке
2. При сборке проекта выскакивает вкладка app, хотелось бы, чтобы она не появлялась

[image: как скрыть лифты]

Comment: В вашем вопросе содержится сразу два вопроса. Переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме. Отредактировать вопрос можно по кнопке [edit] под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы при запуске проекта не выскакивала вкладка «Run», нажмите на редактирование конфигурации в верхнем правом углу:

[image: edit configurations]

Далее, уберите галочку «Activate tool window» и нажмите «OK»:

[image: activate tool window]